# SOAP REQUEST ERROR:SOAP Fault: Server was unable to process request. ---> MaskRequestInfo args(0) is not of type String

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to connect to an API server using SOAP, I have been able to make and view my request, but it keeps returning the error "SOAP Fault: Server was unable to process request. ---> MaskRequestInfo args(0) is not of type String"
I am very new to SOAP, and I am desperately trying to understand its ins and outs, while I am doing that, I just need to get this API. It requires a header in the XML with credentials (replaced with "XXX" in the sample code provided.) Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('https://beta.triseptapi.com/11.0/vax.asmx?WSDL',
array(
'location' => 'https://beta.triseptapi.com/11.0/vax.asmx',
'trace' => 1,)
);
$request=
 "<VAXXML xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' 
 xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns='http://Function_URL'>
  <Header AgencyNumber='xxxx' Contact='xxxx' Login='xxxx' Password='xxxx' 
  Vendor='xxx' Site='xxx' DynamicPackageID='xxx' />
  <Request>
   <Content Destination='LAS' />
   <Content Destination='MCO' />
  </Request>
 </VAXXML>";
$result = array();
$params = array("length" => "1", "string" => $request);
try {
 $result = $client->__soapCall('HotelListRequest', $params);
}
catch (SoapFault $e)
{
 echo "SOAP Fault: ".$e->getMessage()."<br />\n";
}
echo "<pre>";
echo htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequestHeaders())."\n";
echo htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest())."\n";
echo "Response:\n".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponseHeaders())."\n";
echo htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse())."\n";
echo "</pre>";
var_dump($result);?>

sends to the server:
POST /11.0/vax.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: beta.triseptapi.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.6.35
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://www.triseptsolutions.com/VAXXMLPortal110/VAX/HotelListRequest"
Content-Length: 589


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.triseptsolutions.com/VAXXMLPortal110/VAX"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:HotelListRequest/><param1>&lt;Header AgencyNumber='xxx' Contact='xxx' Login='xxx' Password='xxx' Vendor='APV' Site='xxx' DynamicPackageID='xxx' /&gt;&#13;
                &lt;Request&gt;&#13;
                    &lt;Content Destination='LAS' /&gt;&#13;
                    &lt;Content Destination='MCO' /&gt;&#13;
                  &lt;/Request&gt;</param1></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

server returns:
Response:
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 11 Feb 2019 20:00:14 GMT
Content-Length: 433

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; MaskRequestInfo args(0) is not of type String</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

This is the wsdl function:

```
POST /11.0/vax.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: beta.triseptapi.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://www.triseptsolutions.com/VAXXMLPortal110/VAX/HotelListRequest"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <HotelListRequest xmlns="http://www.triseptsolutions.com/VAXXMLPortal110/VAX">
      <requestXml>string</requestXml>
    </HotelListRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <HotelListRequestResponse xmlns="http://www.triseptsolutions.com/VAXXMLPortal110/VAX">
      <HotelListRequestResult>string</HotelListRequestResult>
    </HotelListRequestResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
SOAP 1.2
The following is a sample SOAP 1.2 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

POST /11.0/vax.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: beta.triseptapi.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <HotelListRequest xmlns="http://www.triseptsolutions.com/VAXXMLPortal110/VAX">
      <requestXml>string</requestXml>
    </HotelListRequest>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <HotelListRequestResponse xmlns="http://www.triseptsolutions.com/VAXXMLPortal110/VAX">
      <HotelListRequestResult>string</HotelListRequestResult>
    </HotelListRequestResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
```

The request should look like the following:

```
<HotelListRequest xmlns="http://www.triseptsolutions.com/VAXXMLPortal110/VAX">

  <requestXml>

    <VAXXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.triseptsolutions.com/HotelList/Request/11.0">

    <Header AgencyNumber="xxxx" Contact="XXXX"  Login="XXXXXX" Password="XXXXX" Vendor="xxx" Site="VAXXML" DynamicPackageId="xxxx" />

    <Request>

    <Content Destination="LAS" />

    <Content Destination="MCO" />

    </Request>

    </VAXXML>

  </requestXml>

</HotelListRequest>
```

Comment: It's a little difficult to diagnose without being able to look at the schema and definitions for the request (https://beta.triseptapi.com/11.0/vax.asmx?WSDL and https://beta.triseptapi.com/11.0/vax.asmx?XSD). I tried navigating to the links in your code but they are timing out. If I had to guess, I'd say it is expecting an argument called `MaskRequestInfo`, which is not provided in your request.

Comment: The API is protected by IP whitelisting, which is most likely why you cannot see them. I added the wsdl function above. 'length' and 'string' are the placeholders that need replacing